# Python Regex to match time format works - why?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a function that needs to match hour/minute/seconds in order to allow the user to provide a time argument on the command line in a more convenient fashion than just specifying the number of seconds.

The formats it needs to accept include:

```
hh:mm:ss
   mm:ss
      ss
```

I found a python regex that works at the following location: http://blog.yjl.im/2012/05/nargs-and-type-check-in-argparse-using.html

The regex is: `'^(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(\d+)$'`.

My question is: Why does it work? I've always thought that I was fairly good with regex, but I'm not able to fully understand this one, even with the aid of my cheatsheets.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: This doesn't work with `dd:hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%28%5Cd%2B%29%3A%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29%3A%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29%24

Comment: You're absolutely correct - as is, it doesn't work for `dd:hh:mm:ss`. But as I noted, I'll be able to extend it to do so. But I'll edit the original post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @simonzack [really ????](http://regex101.com/r/mB3dI7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse with this [non-captring group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) `(?:...)`. It won't captures the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside this non-capturing group. `()` called [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Regex:

```
^(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(\d+)$
```

Explanation:

- `(?:(\d+):)?` matches the first two digits+`:`(ie, `hh:`) , captures only the digits and stored it into a group. `?` makes it's presence as optional. So it may or may not occur.
- `(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?` And the second `(\d+):` matches `mm:` , it captures only the digits, and this must be present. So it matches `mm:` if `hh:` is present or not.`?` after the non-capturing group makes the whole presence as optional. So `hh:mm:` may or may not occur.
- `(\d+)$` Captures one or more digits (ie, `ss`)and it must be followed by a line end anchor.

Comment: and my suggestion is to use `\d{2}` instead of `\d+`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That gives me a basic understanding of what's going on. I think it's the presence of the non-capturing group that threw me for a loop.

Comment: see this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mB3dI7/1) link and the groups at the right side. Group 1 == hh, group 2 = mm, group 3 = ss

Comment: Ya - I've already got that up from your comment above. That's what made it click for me. I think what I'm going to have to do is build a number of regexes along similar lines to really "get" it.